# Displaying a div on click of select menu without showing the drop down JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have to make a customized drop down menu using JavaScript. On click of select box dropdown appears with the options, I need to customize the appearance of that menu.

My approach is to have a div with the options in it and required styling, when user clicks the select menu that div should appear instead of displaying drop down.

I tried using `onclick()` events but the dropdown menu appears before and then the div appears. This is not helping the cause.

Please suggest me how to achieve such requirement.

Comment: "a customized drop down menu using javascript" does not provide enough detail to answer this question. Consider adding your HTML output to this question.

Comment: I need to cutomize following HTML block: <select><option>Some Option</option></select>

Comment: Did you try call https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could hide the options?

```
option { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not complete replace the  with your own DIV completely?

Comment: Presumably for correctness with browsers that don't support javascript. It also makes it easier for robots and things like screen readers.

Comment: If the browser doesn't support JS (which ones??!, please tell!) then the onclick will never work regardless. Screen readers are completely capable of reading non-form-based SELECT replacement because the same content will appear in the HTML.

Comment: There are browsers like links (which is text based), but much more likely is that the user has disabled javascript. Additionally, the advantage in using an actual select tag is that some program reading the page, whether it be a search engine spider, readability extension (like Safari reader), or something else that people will design in the future, will know how to format it properly. A screen reader could ask the person which option to select, for example. Without a select tag, it wouldn't know what the user was supposed to do.

Comment: You're talking about LYNX, not "links". So if you want to use a browser from 1995, would you really be expecting things to work? Properly-formed unordered as replacement for SELECT lists are perfectly readable by any screen-reader. Your argument may have been valid 10 years ago, but it no longer is.

Comment: I think the links that I was referring to is based on LYNX. However, that's beside the point. The more semantic information you put in, the more future and backwards compatible you are. This is why HTML5 has elements like aside and nav. Sure, you could just use tons of divs or lists, but if you be more specific, devices can get more out of your website. In this specific context, this means that extensions can autofill the form properly. It means that something in the future with an alternate entry method can do its job properly. It means that users without javascript can use the website.